# Regular expression doesn't work in Rust, what's wrong?

Tags: regex, rust

```
^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$
```

program has panicked with error: unrecognized escape sequence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not post the error message? It literally points to the problem:

```
regex parse error:
    ^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$
                  ^^
error: unrecognized escape sequence
```

So... The error is telling you that `\/` is an unrecognized escape sequence. Because `/` is not a regex meta character, so I don't know why you're escaping it. So change all occurrences of `\/` to `/`:

```
^((?:https?:)?//)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed/|v/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$
```

Comment: i tried, but also RegExp don't work

Comment: It compiles just fine: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4146a732b659e01217c1fd76cb849a8c --- Please consider spending a bit more time to provide more detail to your question. You need help us help you.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b9a470ad2e01b1d47c0c853e0bbf6d59
try this, nothing to print

Comment: ... that's a different question. Your original question asks about escape sequences. And you never actually say what "works" means.

Comment: Your regex is using `^` and `$`, which anchor it to the beginning and end of the text. It looks like you want to be line anchors too, which you can do by enabling multi-line mode. Put `(?m)` at the beginning of your regex and you'll see matches. In the future, please please please add more detail to your questions. Answering this question has been very frustrating for me because of the missing detail in your question.

Comment: okay, sorry, i'm a novice in stackoverflow

Comment: If I answered your question, then please mark this as the answer.